# Gradle sync failed: Could not find method external() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle sync failed: Could not find method external() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

This is what comes up when I try to refresh all gradle projects. I'm quite new to android studio and i'm using ubuntu. I have looked everywhere on the internet for a solution but I cant seem to find one that solves the problem for me.So do you know what the problem is and how I can solve it.

This is my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


dependencies {
    external files('app/libs/junit-4.12-JavaDoc.jar')
    compile files('app/libs/junit-4.12(1).jar')
}
    apply plugin: 'maven'
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
defaultConfig {

// Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "19.0.1"
}
dependencies {
    merged files("libs/graniteds.swc")
}
```

Thank you in advance